# Thunderbird: answer with different color as in Outlook

Tags: thunderbird, colors

In thunderbird, I would like to intersperse my answers within the body of the message I am responding to, with all my new text appearing in some other color.  I only know a very tedious way of doing that.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

#### How do I reply in-line in a new colour?

> I would like to intersperse my answers within the body of the message I am responding to, with all my new text appearing in some other color

You can use the **Formatting Bar**.

The [Quote Colors 0.3](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/quote-colors/versions/)  addon allows the colour of quoted text to be configured (but this appears to be only for reading emails).

---

#### How do I change the reply colour using the Formatting Bar?

- Make sure the Formatting Bar is displayed.

  `View` > `Toolbars` > `Formatting Bar`
- Click on the foreground font colour button, select a color, and press OK.

  The foreground font colour button is the black area shown by the read arrow:

> [image]

- The selected colour will be used when you start typing your reply.

---

#### What is the Quote Colors addon?

> Quote Colors is an add-on for Thunderbird and the mail & newsgroup client of SeaMonkey.
>
> It allows you to assign text and background colors to different quote levels which are applied when reading or printing mail/news messages. Five quote levels can be configured with distinct colors.
>   You can choose between two quoting display modes: graphical quoting with colored bars around quoted paragraphs (default), and traditional plain text quoting where each quoted line starts with one or more ">" characters. In graphical quoting, the color, position and style of the bars is adjustable.
>
> Additionally, this add-on enables you to set up some basic message display options such as text, background, link and signature colors.

Source [Quote Colors 0.3](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/quote-colors/versions/)

Comment: I find the formatting procedure you described cumbersome for interspersing responses in a detailed email.  - -  Apparently Quot Colors is not compatible with my version of Thunderbird, 31.5.0.  (The most up-to-date version is 38.1.0 but I like to let the dust settle a little before I update.)

Comment: @aparente001 Is this addon any better [Color Text Compose Buttons 3.3.0](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/color-text-compose-buttons/)?

Comment: It's one click to select a color ...

Comment: thanks for the suggestion also; I have used that on a different computer that is running an older version of Thunderbird.  But now either I'm doing something wrong or it's not compatible with this version.  I have done Customize but can't find the icon to drag.

Comment: I got it to work on the second computer.